# Посчитать количество не пустых переменных

Tags: php

```
$count = 0;

if (!empty($row['img1'])) {
  $count++;
}

if (!empty($row['img2'])) {
  $count++;
}

if (!empty($row['img3'])) {
  $count++;
}

echo $count;
```

Можно ли посчитать количество не пустых переменных более простым методом?

Comment: Там есть ещё другие, к примеру $row['text']. Но посчитать нужно только эти три

Comment: **Не нужно** хранить картиночки в колонках с циферками. Такого рода данные хранятся в отдельной таблице. И тогда не будет возникать вопроса, "как посчитать пустые"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто сложи их: https://ideone.com/4fvwtA

```
$row = [ 'img2' => 'img-2', 'text' => 'text', 'img3' => null, 'img4' => 'img-4' ];
echo !empty($row['img1']) + !empty($row['img2']) + !empty($row['img3']) + !empty($row['img4']);
```

```
2
```

Comment: исходный код хотя бы скроллинг не вызывает

Comment: @Ипатьев, я добавил 4е поле чтобы убедиться, что получится 2, а не 1. При 3 полях никакого скроллинга.